# Determine if NamedPipeClientStream is connected

Tags: c#, process, stream, pipe

I've problem with process communication using PipeConnection

My idea is:

> A - process A 
>   B - process B
>   1. A(pile client) wants to send message to B(pipe server)
>   2. B reads message and disconects.
>
> > 2.1 If B needs to ansver
> >     2.2 B(pipe client) connects to A(pile server)
> >     2.3 A reads message and disconects.

The problem appears if A sends message to B and than imedlitley wants to send another message again

Code sample:

```
//Server
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (NamedPipeServerStream server = new NamedPipeServerStream("EOG", PipeDirection.In))
        {
            StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(server);

            while (true)
            {
                server.WaitForConnection();
                Console.WriteLine("Conected to client");
                try
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(sr.ReadLine());
                    server.Disconnect();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
                }
            }
            sr.Dispose();
        }
    }
}



//Client
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (NamedPipeClientStream client = new NamedPipeClientStream(".", "EOG", PipeDirection.Out))
        {
            StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(client);
            while (true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Message: ");
                sw.WriteLine(Console.ReadLine());
                if (!client.IsConnected)
                    client.Connect();
                sw.Flush();
            }
            sw.Dispose();
        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

Comment: I should have an answer for you shortly. I've found a way to do this with multi-threading, but I'm still getting a casting error when it gets a result.